# Image involuntarily resizes when drawn

Tags: c#, image, size

I have an Image Which is 100 X 100,
But when i want to draw it, it gets resized for some odd resone,
here is the code:

```
  w = 100;
  h = image1.height + image2.height + image3.height;//every image height is 100
  SpaceShip = (Image)new Bitmap(SpaceShip, new Size(w, h));
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(SpaceShip);
  g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
  g.DrawImage(image1, new Point(0, 0));
  g.DrawImage(image2, new Point(0,image1.Height));
  g.DrawImage(image3, new Point(0, image1.Height +image2.Height));

  g.Dispose();
```

this is the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJt42.png

the triangle is 100x100 with transperant backround.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of DrawImage that takes source/dest rectangles and GraphicsUnit.Pixel. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx

This is happening because of DPI scaling.

Comment: Either that or set all your images to the same dpi resolution as your screen or your target image.

Comment: Thanks, But I found that doing this also works:
Image _img1 = (Image)new Bitmap(img1, (new Size(100, 100)));